# How can I override PersistenceTestKit config for a custom journal?

Tags: akka.net, akka-persistence

`PersistenceTestKit` has a constructor which takes a configuration object as an argument. This config seems to be ignored when it comes to custom journal implementation.

First of all, I have no interest in implementing a custom journal, but I can't figure out how to create a query for the default `TestJournal`.

So I thought I could implemented my own `FakeJournal` so I have full control over its data in my test.

That didn't work. I have defined a custom configuration for my journal and passed it to `PersistenceTestKit`, but the values are ignored or overwritten.

My config is parsed correctly, ie there are no errors and I can find all my values in the parsed result.

When I inspect the actual config via the `Settings` property, I can't see my custom configuration at all.

Does this mean there are certain values one cannot override for `PersistenceTestKit`?

If the `TestJournal` property cannot be overriden, is it even possible to get access to the `TestJournal`? Which messages does it support?

In the end, all I need is a query for the journal. Is it possible to create one for the current journal? For the test journal?

Comment: Have you tried to set it up like ie. the persistence tests in akka.net repository? https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/contrib/persistence/Akka.Persistence.Sqlite.Tests/SqliteJournalSpec.cs

Comment: It seems like `PersistenceTestKit` overrides the config. When I reverted to `TestKit`, my passed config worked as expected.